# VSTS - dependecy mapping with TIA builds doesn't work

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task

We tried to implement the dependency mapping explained in this Microsoft post, but it doesn't work.

[Microsoft dependency mapping implementation example](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2017/08/04/accelerated-continuous-testing-with-test-impact-analysis-part-4/)

We have enabled in our build the "Run only impacted test" and set the "Settings file" and TIA.usermapfile from visual studio task.

After that we have created the XML file at the root of the solution, and set parameters for executing specific test from FullyQualifiedName contained in the changes from check-in.

We have verified that the XML file is correctly located at the `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` in the build agent server.

We have checked in some modifications which impact the repositories classes.

As you can see, there is no information about the `TIAmap.xml` file in the Test assemblies log, and the tests were not started, whereas the code changes impact the repository folder.

We have more two thousand tests and there are none that are launched.

Do you have any idea why the tests that would impact and not impact the repositories folder aren't run?

Comment: Can you share the detail build log on the OneDrive? (Set system.debug variable to true, then queue build) On the other hand, can you reproduce this issue with the new project? If so, you can share this sample project on the OneDrive.

Comment: Hello Starian Chen, could you write me at pedro.esteves@winbiz.ch. We don't want to share information in public websites. Thank you, for you help

Comment: Can you share a simple sample project that can reproduce this issue?

Comment: Hello it will be difficult to share a sample project but i could you send the logs with system debug at true.Please write me an email.

Comment: Can't find the reason from the log, share a sample project is better for troubleshooting.